# Remove contents from textfile in php

Tags: php

I have a textfile that contains some text as:

```
first line
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world hello world hello world
```

I want to remove text from my textfile that matches `first line` in my file.

how can be it possible using php?

Comment: What you have tried for it???

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, we are not here to code for you. I recommend you read: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you trying to replace `first line` literally or just the first line of any file? Have you brought the file into PHP already? Please post your current code.  If the literal see http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

Comment: Yes **chris85** , i want to replace _first line_ text from my file

Answer (score 0):

Read your text file and store it in a variable, then use regex to find the line, remove it, and write it back into your file

[regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: i followed **preg_replace** function but can't understand about _how to remove text from my file_

Comment: @user3078111
take a look at these examples: http://lzone.de/examples/PHP%20preg_replace